# Reset numbering in example using Covington package

Tags: numbering, appendices, linguistics, examples, covington

I'm currently trying to reset the numbering of my examples in my appendix. I'm using the [`covington`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/covington) package, and my problem is that the examples of the appendix follow the numbering of the previous examples that are in the text. How can I change this?

This is what I have:

```
\appendix
\appendixpage 
\section{Stimulus material}\label{Stimulus}
\subsection{Test stimuli}
Some text here
\begin{example}
\footnotesize
\gll El vecino escucha que el padre del ni\~{n}o toca el piano
The neighbor hears that the father$_{N1}$ {of the} boy$_{N2}$ plays the piano
\glt 
\glend
\end{example}
```

[image: output]

What I would like is the example to start in (1), and also to be able to include two sub-examples, so (1.1) and (1.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That package uses the same counter for examples as is normally used for equations. You can restart it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{covington}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\begin{example}
  Main example
\end{example}

\appendix
% Restart example counter:
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\section{Bar}
\begin{example}
  Appendix example
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

(Note that this is a complete example that you can compile yourself to see the result. That's the kind of MWEs we like in questions on this site.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. And I'll do my best next time I post a question (I tend to assume too much sometimes, so I do not write everything).